# How to remove Objects from an array of objects using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an array of objects where some objects are undefined and I want to know how to remove them i got it how many of them but don't know how to remove them from an array of objects. i know this method to use but i want some more standard way to do it

```
    const data = [
        {
            roleDoc:{
                name:"A"
            }
        },
        { roleDoc: undefined }
        ,{
            roleDoc:{
                name:"c"
            }
        },{
            roleDoc:{
                name:"c"
            }
        },
        { roleDoc: undefined },
        ,{
            roleDoc:{
                name:"c"
            }
        }

    ]
 const xy = []
data.forEach(item => {
    if(item.roleDoc !== undefined){
       xy.push(item) 
    }
    else{
        console.log('hello')
    }
})
console.log(xy)
```

expected output is

```
const data = [
  {
    roleDoc: {
      name: "A"
    }
  },

  ,
  {
    roleDoc: {
      name: "c"
    }
  },
  {
    roleDoc: {
      name: "c"
    }
  },

  ,
  {
    roleDoc: {
      name: "c"
    }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and `!!` only matched valid

```js
const data = [ { roleDoc:{ name:"A" } }, { roleDoc: undefined } ,{ roleDoc:{ name:"c" } },{ roleDoc:{ name:"c" } }, { roleDoc: undefined },{ roleDoc:{ name:"c" } }];

let res = data.filter(a=> !!a.roleDoc);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove `undefined` ones.

Try the following:

```js
 const data = [{ roleDoc:{ name:"A" } }, { roleDoc: undefined } ,{ roleDoc:{ name:"c"}},{roleDoc:{name:"c"} }, { roleDoc: undefined },{ roleDoc:{name:"c"}}];

const result = data.filter(e => e.roleDoc);

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function programming approach using the [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```js
const data = [
    {
        roleDoc: {
            name: "A"
        }
    },
    { 
        roleDoc: undefined 
    },
    {
        roleDoc: {
            name: "c"
        }
    },
    {
        roleDoc: {
            name: "c"
        }
    },
    { 
        roleDoc: undefined
    },
    {
        roleDoc: {
            name: "c"
        }
    }
];

const arrayWithoutUndefineds = data.filter(el => typeof el.roleDoc !== 'undefined');

console.log(arrayWithoutUndefineds);
```

Note that the expression used could be simplied. However, so it it clear what it happening I will leave it there.